# nested local declarations in ML of NJ

Tags: sml, smlnj

hello everyone I have this snippet of the code:

```
local
 helper(f, i, j) = local
                    fun NTimesF(f, n:int) = 
                    if n = 1 then fn (x) => f(x)
                    else fn (x) => f(NTimesF(f, n - 1)(x));
                   in
                    if(i <= j) then NTimesF(f, i) :: helper(f, (i+1), j)
                    else []
                   end
in  
 fun compList f n = helper(f, 1, n);
end;
```

I need to write program which receives some function f and integer n and produce list of functions such as [f1, f2, ... fn] <- fn is the composition of the function n times but every time I receive an error:

```
- stdIn:1.1-2.9 Error: syntax error: deleting  LOCAL ID LPAREN
stdIn:2.10-2.14 Error: syntax error: deleting  COMMA ID COMMA
stdIn:2.16-2.25 Error: syntax error: deleting  RPAREN EQUALOP LOCAL
stdIn:3.6-3.17 Error: syntax error: deleting  FUN ID
stdIn:4.6-4.10 Error: syntax error: deleting  IF ID
stdIn:4.15-4.22 Error: syntax error: deleting  THEN FN
stdIn:4.27-4.31 Error: syntax error: deleting  DARROW ID
stdIn:5.6-5.13 Error: syntax error: deleting  ELSE FN
stdIn:5.16-5.22 Error: syntax error: deleting  RPAREN DARROW ID
stdIn:6.8-7.8 Error: syntax error: deleting  IN IF
stdIn:7.17-7.29 Error: syntax error: deleting  THEN ID
stdIn:8.6-8.13 Error: syntax error: deleting  ELSE LBRACKET RBRACKET
stdIn:9.8-11.5 Error: syntax error: deleting  END IN FUN
```

it seems that my nested local declarations are wrong, can somebody please explain why?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There are two ways to define local functions and variables in SML: `local ... in ... end` and `let ... in ... end`.

The difference between `local` and `let` is that with `local` what comes between `in` and `end` are one or more variable or function declarations. With `let` what comes between `in` and `end` is an expression.

Unlike `local`, `let` is an expression and the value of a `let` expression is the value of the expression between `in` and `end`.

Since in your case you have an expression between `in` and `end` (and you want the function to evaluate to the result of that expression), you need to use `let`, not `local`.

Comment: @sepp2k: thank you very much, I changed two "local" to two "let", anyway I receive 4 first errors, may it be something else?

Comment: @rookie: No, the outer `local` is correct. You only need to change the inner `local` to `let` (the one that contains an expression).

Comment: @rookie: Also you're missing a `fun` before `helper (f, i, j)`

Comment: @sepp2k: anyway 3 first errors are the same and final is: stdIn:10.1-11.5 Error: syntax error: deleting  IN FUN:(, it means that I have error on 10 and 11 rows?

Comment: @rookie: If I change the inner `local` to `let` and add the `fun` it works fine for me.

Comment: @sepp2k: thanks, its ok now, I wasn't vigilant:), as always You are the best!