# Difference between "local" and "let" in SML

Tags: local, sml, let

I couldn't find a beginner friendly answer to what the difference between the "local" and "let" keywords in SML is. Could someone provide a simple example please and explain when one is used over the other?

Comment: Probably related answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4297171/1627585. "The difference between `local` and `let` ..."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### (TL;DR)

1. Use `case ... of ...` when you only have one temporary binding.
2. Use `let ... in ... end` for very specific helper functions.
3. Never use `local ... in ... end`. Use opaque modules instead.

#### Adding some thoughts on use-cases to [sepp2k's fine answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4297171/235908):

- *(Summary)* `local ... in ... end` is a declaration and `let ... in ... end` is an expression, so that effectively limits where they can be used: Where declarations are allowed (e.g. at the top level or inside a module), and inside value declarations (`val` and `fun`), respectively.

  But so what? It often seems that either can be used. The [Rosetta Stone QuickSort code](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithms/Quicksort#Standard_ML), for example, could be structured using either, since the helper functions are only used once:

  ```
  (* First using local ... in ... end *)
  local
      fun par_helper([], x, l, r) = (l, r)
        | par_helper(h::t, x, l, r) =
            if h <= x
              then par_helper(t, x, l @ [h], r)
              else par_helper(t, x, l, r @ [h])

      fun par(l, x) = par_helper(l, x, [], [])
  in
    fun quicksort [] = []
      | quicksort (h::t) =
          let
            val (left, right) = par(t, h)
          in
            quicksort left @ [h] @ quicksort right
          end
  end

  (* Second using let ... in ... end *)
  fun quicksort [] = []
    | quicksort (h::t) =
        let
          fun par_helper([], x, l, r) = (l, r)
            | par_helper(h::t, x, l, r) = 
                if h <= x
                  then par_helper(t, x, l @ [h], r)
                  else par_helper(t, x, l, r @ [h])

          fun par(l, x) = par_helper(l, x, [], [])

          val (left, right) = par(t, h)
        in
          quicksort left @ [h] @ quicksort right
        end
  ```

#### So let's focus on when it is particularly useful to use one or the other.

- `local ... in ... end` is mainly used when you have one or more temporary declarations (e.g. helper functions) that you want to hide after they're used, but they should be shared between *multiple* non-local declarations. E.g.

  ```
  (* Helper function shared across multiple functions *)
  local
      fun par_helper ... = ...

      fun par(l, x) = par_helper(l, x, [], [])
  in
    fun quicksort [] = []
      | quicksort (h::t) = ... par(t, h) ...

    fun median ... = ... par(t, h) ...
  end
  ```

  If there weren't multiple, you could have used a `let ... in ... end` instead.

  You can always avoid using `local ... in ... end` in favor of *opaque modules* (see below).
- `let ... in ... end` is mainly used when you want to compute temporary results, or deconstruct values of product types (tuples, records), one or more times inside a function. E.g.

  ```
  fun quicksort [] = []
    | quicksort (x::xs) =
      let
        val (left, right) = List.partition (fn y => y < x) xs
      in
        quicksort left @ [x] @ quicksort right
      end
  ```

  Here are some of the benefits of `let ... in ... end`:

  1. A binding is computed *once* per function call (even when used multiple times).
  2. A binding can simultaneously be deconstructed (into `left` and `right` here).
  3. The declaration's scope is limited. (Same argument as for `local ... in ... end`.)
  4. Inner functions may use the arguments of the outer function, or the outer function itself.
  5. Multiple bindings that depend on each other may neatly be lined up.

  And so on... Really, let-expressions are quite nice.

  When a helper function is used once, you might as well nest it inside a `let ... in ... end`.

  Especially if other reasons for using one applies, too.

#### Some additional opinions

1. *(`case ... of ...` is awesome, too.)*

   When you have only one `let ... in ... end` you can instead write e.g.

   ```
   fun quicksort [] = []
     | quicksort (x::xs) =
       case List.partition (fn y => y < x) xs of
         (left, right) => quicksort left @ [x] @ quicksort right
   ```

   These are equivalent. You might like the style of one or the other. The `case ... of ...` has one advantage, though, being that it also work for [*sum types*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_data_type) (`'a option`, `'a list`, etc.), e.g.

   ```
   (* Using case ... of ... *)
   fun maxList [] = NONE
     | maxList (x::xs) =
       case maxList xs of
            NONE => SOME x
          | SOME y => SOME (Int.max (x, y))

   (* Using let ... in ... end and a helper function *)
   fun maxList [] = NONE
     | maxList (x::xs) =
       let
         val y_opt = maxList xs
       in
         Option.map (fn y => Int.max (x, y)) y_opt
       end
   ```

   The one disadvantage of `case ... of ...`: The pattern block does not stop, so nesting them often requires parentheses. You can also combine the two in different ways, e.g.

   ```
   fun move p1 (GameState old_p) gameMap =
       let val p' = addp p1 old_p in
         case getMapPos p' gameMap of
             Grass => GameState p'
           | _     => GameState old_p
       end
   ```

   This isn't so much about *not* using `local ... in ... end`, though.
2. Hiding declarations that won't be used elsewhere is sensible. E.g.

   ```
   (* if they're overly specific *)
   fun handvalue hand =
       let
         fun handvalue' [] = 0
           | handvalue' (c::cs) = cardvalue c + handvalue' cs
         val hv = handvalue' hand
       in
         if hv > 21 andalso hasAce hand
         then handvalue (removeAce hand) + 1
         else hv
       end

   (* to cover over multiple arguments, e.g. to achieve tail-recursion, *)
   (* or because the inner function has dependencies anyways (here: x). *)
   fun par(ys, x) =
       let fun par_helper([], l, r) = (l, r)
             | par_helper(h::t, l, r) =
                 if h <= x
                   then par_helper(t, l @ [h], r)
                   else par_helper(t, l, r @ [h])
       in par_helper(ys, [], []) end
   ```

   And so on. Basically,

   1. If a declaration (e.g. function) will be re-used, don't hide it.
   2. If not, the point of `local ... in ... end` over `let ... in ... end` is void.
3. *(`local ... in ... end` is useless.)*

   You never want to use `local ... in ... end`. Since its job is to isolate one set of helper declarations to a subset of your main declarations, this forces you to group those main declarations according to what they depend on, rather than perhaps a more desired order.

   A better alternative is simply to write a structure, give it a signature and make that signature opaque. That way, all internal declarations can be used freely throughout the module without being exported.

   One example of this in j4cbo's [SML on Stilts web-framework](https://github.com/j4cbo/stilts/blob/c7ba8cfa417dba209fe6287b99b778ef2aed7e72/web/static-server.sml) is the module StaticServer: It exports only `val server : ...`, even though the structure also holds the two declarations `structure U = WebUtil` and `val content_type = ...`.

   ```
   structure StaticServer :> sig

     val server: { basepath: string,
                   expires: LargeInt.int option,
                   headers: Web.header list } -> Web.app

   end = struct

     structure U = WebUtil

     val content_type = fn
           "png" => "image/png"
         | "gif" => "image/gif"
         | "jpg" => "image/jpeg"
         | "css" => "text/css"
         | "js" => "text/javascript"
         | "html" => "text/html"
         | _ => "text/plain" 

     fun server { basepath, expires, headers } (req: Web.request) = ...
   end
   ```

Comment: Just to add a little bit to the confusion, `let` is also available at the module-language level in Standard ML: https://gist.github.com/igstan/a5eee5b03db06e274a0331ab1e019be7. In SML/NJ, `local` is also available in the module language: https://gist.github.com/igstan/d014f0f2737571da69feda323d326052

Answer (score 5):

The short answer is: `local` is a declaration, `let` is an expression. Consequently, they are used in different syntactic contexts, and `local` requires declarations between `in` and `end`, while `let` requires an expression there. It's not much deeper than that.

As @SimonShine mentioned, `local` is often discouraged in favour of using modules.