# Exhaustively destructuring lists in SML

Tags: pattern-matching, sml, smlnj

The SML fragment `... let val (x::xs) = String.explode s in ...` will always complain about an inexhuastive pattern, even if I pattern-match the empty string case in the function definition. Is there some way to modify this so that the match is exhaustive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to use `case` instead of the `let`:

```
... case String.explode s of x::xs => ... | nil => raise Domain
```

Or if you absolutely want to keep the `let`, turn it into a pair:

```
val (x, xs) = case ... of x::xs => (x, xs) | nil => raise Domain
```

You can abstract the latter into a helper function:

```
fun decons (x::xs) = (x, xs)
  | decons nil = raise Domain
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason why `let val (x::xs) = ...` is never exhaustive is because the `val` declaration only has one pattern placeholder (here used for `x::xs`). Lists, being a kind of sum type, has two constructors, `::` and `[]`. As Andreas Rossberg says, `case` is the way to go when you have multiple patterns. See [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39577498/difference-between-local-and-let-in-sml) for an opinionated comparison (TL;DR: I sometimes like to use `case` even when there's only one case.)

> *[...]* even if I pattern-match the empty string case in the function definition

You could consider removing the empty string case, call `String.explode` on all inputs and handle an output of `[]` in the same way as you would handle the empty string case.

So the following code:

```
fun f "" = <foo>
  | f s = case String.explode s of
               x::xs => <bar>
             | []    => raise Fail "impossible"
```

Becomes:

```
fun f s = case String.explode s of
               []    => <foo>
             | x::xs => <bar>
```