# Find the smallest subsequence of k distinct elements in a list

Tags: arrays, sml, smlnj

I am super new to sml. I am trying to write a simple code that takes an array of 5 positions with certain numbers and returns the length of the smallest subarray that contains all numbers. However I am getting many error messages that I cannot find in Google. Can anyone help me? The code is the following

```
 fun Min x y = if x>y then return y else return x
    local
        val a = Array.array (3,0)
        val cordela = Array.array(5,0)
        val k=0
        val front=0
        val tail=0
        val min=5
        update(cordela,0,1)
        update(cordela,1,3)
        update(cordela,2,3)
        update(cordela,3,2)
        update(cordela,4,1)
    in   
        fun loop front = 
            case k>3 of
                if sub(a,sub(cordela,front)-1) = 0 then k=k+1 else()
                update(a,sub(cordela,front)-1),sub(a,sub(cordela,front)-1)+1)
                front = front +1
            | 
                min= Min (front-tail) min
                if sub(a,sub(cordela,front)-1) = 0 then k=k-1 else()
                update(a,sub(cordela,front)-1),sub(a,sub(cordela,front)-1)-1)
                tail=tail+1

            if 5>front then loop front+1 else min
    end
```

The error messages that I get are:

```
pl2.sml:16.13-16.15 Error: syntax error: replacing  OF with  LBRACKET
pl2.sml:18.36 Error: syntax error: inserting  LPAREN
pl2.sml:20.4 Error: syntax error: replacing  BAR with  EQUALOP
pl2.sml:22.5 Error: syntax error: inserting  LPAREN
pl2.sml:26.4 Error: syntax error: inserting  LPAREN
pl2.sml:27.2 Error: syntax error found at END
```

Edit: I am trying to write this code in sml. It is written in c++

```
while(front < N){
        if( k < K ){
            if ( e[cordela[front]-1] == 0 ) k += 1;
            e[cordela[front]-1] +=1;
            front++ ;
        }
        else{
            min = MIN(front - tail ,min);
            if ( e[cordela[tail]-1] ==1 ) k -= 1;
            e[cordela[tail]-1] -= 1;
            tail++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: SML/NJ error messages can be opaque. Note that you are missing a matching `else`, which are not optional in sml.

Comment: @JohnColeman I fixed the else statements but still the errors come up a bit different

Comment: Your `case` makes no sense (where are the `=>` ?). More generally, you seem to be trying to write Java-like code in SML. You are thinking way too imperatively rather than functionally. Also -- why are you using `local` rather than `let`?

Comment: @JohnColeman Thank you , what improvements should I have made in this code in order to work in ML

Comment: It isn't at all clear what you are trying to do. What is the type of the function that you are trying to write? The code is very verbose for SML, but since I don't really know what you are trying to do, I can't make concrete recommendations. There is a lot of confusion on your part about the basic semantics of SML. For example. `if sub(a,sub(cordela,front)-1) = 0 then k=k+1 else()` won't type check. since the type of `k=k+1` is boolean (it doesn't replace `k` by `k+1`, instead it compares `k` and `k+1`, evaluating to `false`), but the type of the `()` at the end is `unit`, not boolean.

Comment: @JohnColeman Please see the edit

Comment: "I am trying to write this code in sml. It is written in c++" --- why? Just write SML code in SML. You are trying to write imperative code in a functional language, Forget about C++. It isn't really relevant here. Also -- you never clearly explained just what it is that you are trying to do. What is the *type* of the function that you are trying to write?

Comment: @JohnColeman I am trying to write a function that finds the length of the smallest subarray that contains all the elements that are on the big array. Ex : 1 2 2 3 2  2 2 3 1 Answer : 3

Comment: Are you sure that you mean array, rather than list? Also, when I was asking for type, I was looking for something like `int list -> int`

Comment: @JohnColeman  It could be both , The numbers are given as input from a file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190954/discussion-between-maverick98-and-john-coleman).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As John Coleman says, SML/NJ will not give very helpful error messages. You could try and [install Moscow ML](https://mosml.org/) instead, since it gives better error messages. Unfortunately, there are some things wrong with this code at a syntactic level that makes it difficult for the compiler to give a meaningful error. Here are some hints to get the syntax right so that you can focus on the algorithm problems:

- [Don't use `local`, use `let`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39577498/difference-between-local-and-let-in-sml).
- Match each `(` with a `)`; you have too many `)`s.
- Declare `fun loop ... = ...` inside `let` and `in`.
- Once you've done that, a template for the function that solves your problem could look like:

  ```
  fun smallest_subarray (needles : Array.array, haystack : Array.array) =
      let
        val ... = ...
        fun loop ... = ...
      in
        if Array.length needles > Array.length haystack
        then ...
        else loop ...
      end
  ```

What if there's no solution to the problem, what will the function return? `~1`? `NONE`?

If you're trying to convert a C++ program to SML, try and include the function part in such a way that it's obvious what identifiers are arguments to the function, and try to name them logically; I have no idea what `cordela`, `e` and `k` are, or if `N` is a function of the size of the input array, or a constant.

Since an idiomatic solution in SML uses recursion (the function calling itself) rather than iteration (`while`), you are dealing with both a non-trivial algorithm problem *and* another paradigm. Try instead to solve a similar, but simpler problem where the algorithm is more trivial and apply the recursion paradigm.

For example, try and write a function that finds the position of an element in a sorted array using binary search:

```
fun find x arr =
    let
      fun loop ... = ...
    in
      loop ...
    end
```

The `loop` function would take the search bounds (e.g. `i` and `j`) as argument and return either `SOME i` if `x` is found at position `i`, or `NONE`. You could extend this problem in the direction of your original problem by then trying to write a function that determines if an input array, `needles`, occurs in another input array, `haystack`, in the order given in `needles`. You could first assume that `needles` and `haystack` are sorted, and then assume that they're not.

Comment: As usual, your answers are very informative but still manage to be not so informative that they leave nothing for the student to complete.

Comment: @SimonShine I tried to solve the problem proposed at the end of your answer

`fun find x arr=
 let 
   val j=length arr
   fun loop i  = if (x== sub(arr,i)) then return i else return loop i-1
 in
   loop j 
 end`

Is this correct?

Comment: @maverick98: StackOverflow comments are not ideal for discussing partial solutions to other problems than what the original question was about. And no. :)