# Why do I use `let` and not just `val` to declare a variable inside a function in SML?

Tags: sml

In SML, I've been taught the idiomatic way to define a variable local to the function as:

```
fun correct_fun() =
    let val x = 1
    in x + 2
    end
```

Why do I have to use `let`, and not just `val` like so:

```
fun incorrect_fun() =
    val x = 1
    x + 2
```

The `incorrect_fun()` throws an error but I don't understand why. Why can't val be used inside a function without `let`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why can't `val` be used inside a function without `let`?

Because `val` is a kind of declaration, `let` is a kind of expression, and a function body is an expression.

The syntactic structure of a `let`-expression is `let`*`dec`*`in`*`exp`*`end`. So in using a `let`-expression as the function body, the *`exp`* within the `let` is equivalent to the function body, but with an extended, local scope of whatever *`dec`* adds.

The `let`-expression lets you use any kind of declaration, not just `val` declarations.

For example, you can use exception handling as a control-flow mechanism used for backtracking, and you can nest helper functions that are only used locally and possibly takes multiple arguments for storing a temporary result, but you may not want to expose the exception or the helper functions. So for the [Eight Queens puzzle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight_queens_puzzle), you might refine [this solution](https://www.fys.ku.dk/~arvid/FP-2.pdf) (from *supplemental notes on functional programming, pp. 140-143*, by Niels Andersen):

```
fun concatMap f xs = String.concat (List.map f xs)
fun concatTab f n = String.concat (List.tabulate (n, f))

fun dots n = concatTab (fn _ => ". ") n
fun show ys = concatMap (fn y => dots (y - 1) ^ "* " ^ dots (8 - y) ^ "\n") ys

fun queen dims =
    let exception Queen
        fun beats ((x,y),(x1,y1)) = (* x = x1 *)
                         (* orelse *)  y = y1
                            orelse x + y = x1 + y1
                            orelse x - y = x1 - y1

        fun safe ((x, y), _, []) = true
          | safe ((x, y), x1, y1::ys) =
            not (beats ((x, y), (x1, y1))) andalso safe ((x, y), x1 + 1, ys)

        fun queen' ((0, _), ys) = ys
          | queen' ((_, 0), _) = raise Queen
          | queen' ((x, y), ys)  =
            if safe ((x, y), x + 1, ys)
              then queen' ((x - 1, 8), y :: ys)
                   handle Queen => queen' ((x, y - 1), ys)
              else queen' ((x, y - 1), ys)

    in queen' (dims, []) end
```

Demonstrating it;

```
- print (show (queen ((8,8))));
. . . . * . . . 
. . . . . . * . 
. * . . . . . . 
. . . . . * . . 
. . * . . . . . 
* . . . . . . . 
. . . * . . . . 
. . . . . . . *
```

When you're using `let`-expressions to mainly declare temporary values, you could also consider going with a `case-of`. See the Q&A's for [Difference between "local" and "let" in SML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39577498/difference-between-local-and-let-in-sml) and [nested local declarations in ML of NJ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4297123/nested-local-declarations-in-ml-of-nj) for that.

Comment: So `val` cannot be used inside a function body because the function body must be an expression? On the other hand, using `val` "outside" (i.e. when I write `val x = 1` in a script) is fine because "outside" allows declaration? (These things sound like basics of functional programming that I didn't know!)

Comment: @Heisenberg: When by "outside the function" you mean either before or after the function declaration (e.g. at the top-level, or inside the first part of a `let`-expression, or a number of other places), then yes, you can have declarations of all kinds there. This isn't a property of functional programming, but specifically a property of the syntax of Standard ML. In the [lambda calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus), which is the theoretical basis for functional programming, you only have lambda expressions, no declarations of any kind.